# Get the min() value from columns where duplicates are associated with ids

Tags: sql, min

So, to simplify my problem is as follows:

A. I pass in CustomerID, there can be multiple Orders per Customer. I need to find the minimum ProductID per Order per Customer.

B. Once that is complete, I need run the main query (to return the dataset) in which I would like to display all the Orders, along with Category and Code (per Product). The result should display NULL for Product, Category and Code where the ProductID <> the ProductID found in Part A.

Thanks

(All these are separate tables with foreign keys. I can handle the joins, it's just the "**minimum** ProductID per Order per Customer" thing that's throwing me.)

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide much information about your specific database schema, so an exact answer is hard to provide.  Basically, you want to use a combination of MIN and Group By (and perhaps a join or two depending on your schema).

The following provides a rough example:

```
select min(ProductID) from Orders o
inner join Customers c 
  on o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
group by (productID)
  having c.CustomerID = <customer id value>
```

Regards,